# is there a command for executing return/enter key?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I came across this awesome macros extension, coupled with the commands extension for the status bar and damn is there some productivity to be had.

I can pull up the quickOpen tab with the command

```
{
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen", 
    "args": "thing.vue"
}
```

and auto-fill it with `"thing.vue"`

but I can't get vscode to execute a return/enter command

For 1 thing, it seems that `{"command": "type"}` does type into the quickOpen input, even if running a `workbench.action.focusQuickOpen` command before running the type command, even synchronously and not run in a macro, seems to type at the last cursor position in the file instead of the quickOpen input

```
"macros": {
        "goToInv": [
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen", 
                "args": "thing.vue"
            },
            "workbench.action.focusQuickOpen",
        ]
},
"commands.commands": [
    {
        "command": "macros.goToInv",
        "alignment": "left",
        "text": "$(package) inv"
    },
    {
        "command": "type", 
        "text": "Type",
        "arguments": [{
            "text": "thing.vue"
        }]
    }
]
```

running `macros.goToInv` from the status bar will bring up the filled up quickOpen input, and then running `type` from the status bar will type `"thing.vue"` into the last cursor position of the file.

So even if there was a command for executing the enter key, it probably wouldn't work.

Is there an `executeQuickOpenItem` command?

There is a `workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem` command but it doesn't seem to execute the quickOpen query

Thanks for taking the time to have a read of my thoughts..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I really want this :)

Comment: @jcdizzle94 unfortunately no :'(