'ENTER' as command in VS Code keybinding.json

"command": "runCommands",
"key": "shift+f1",
"args": {
"commands": [
"workbench.action.files.save",
"#######.compile"
--> here i want a command for ENTER
]
}

I would like to use the key 'ENTER' for my shortcut in the code above because for compiling i get always asked in VS Code, which source i want to compile. So i have my shortcut with shift+F1 but have to enter again the pop up. I compile always the current file so maybe you have another idea for my problem.

related?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47889404/11107541

You should say how - like what extension - you are using for the compile step.  And show the pop-up that you want to accept.

The pop up is attached at the bottom of this post.
Its a self made extension so not available for public.
